# List of Active Directory users who do not have a Exchange 2013 mailbox

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server, exchange-server-2013

We delete users through Exchange 2013 which leaves behind the user account in Active Directory.

Using a PowerShell snippet, how can I get a list of Active Directory users who do not have a Exchange 2013 mailbox?

i.e. Active Directory users that need to be deleted.

Comment: If you delete a User on Exchange site he'll be deleted in AD too. So you want a list of all Users who never had a Mailbox or do you only deactive the user in Exchange, which would leave behind all the Users?

Comment: I don't see that behaviour. The AD user is left behind. The Exchange mailbox is deleted not deactivated. I want a list of all AD users with no mailbox.

Comment: Well.. `Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(msExchMailboxGuid=*)"` will give you all People with a Mailbox. You can either compare the lists then or reverse the search.. Although `msExchMailboxGuid=$Null` doesn't work

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

I'm confused. When you delete a mailbox in Exchange 2013, the AD user is also deleted. If you disable it the AD user is kept, but the attributes are removed. So if you really want to remove someone, why not delete the mailbox?

> The primary difference between deleting and disabling a mailbox is
>   that when you disable a mailbox, the Exchange attributes are removed
>   from the corresponding Active Directory user account, but the user
>   account is retained. When you delete a mailbox, both the Exchange
>   attributes and the Active Directory user account are deleted.

Source: [Disable or delete a mailbox @ TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863434(v=exchg.150).aspx)

You could try to use the not-operator, ex:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(!msExchMailboxGuid=*)"
```

or

```
Get-ADUser -Filter '-not msExchMailboxGuid -like "*"'
```

or

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'msExchMailboxGuid -notlike "*"'
```